# asp.net c#.No mapping exists from object type System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload to a known managed provider native type

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following error :

> error:
>         No mapping exists from object type System.Web.UI.WebControls.FileUpload to a known managed provider
>   native type.

My program is :

```
public partial class HrInfo: System.Web.UI.Page {


    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

    }

    protected void btn_insrt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        try {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SYSTEM-6-PC;Initial Catalog=HRMS;Integrated Security=True");
            con.Open();

            FileUpload img = (FileUpload) imgUpload;
            Byte[] imgByte = null;
            if (img.HasFile && img.PostedFile != null) {
                //To create a PostedFile
                HttpPostedFile File = imgUpload.PostedFile;
                //Create byte Array with file len
                imgByte = new Byte[File.ContentLength];
                //force the control to load data in array
                File.InputStream.Read(imgByte, 0, File.ContentLength);
            }
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO HR_information([HRName],[HRCode],[Designation],[Department],[Qulification],[DateOfBirth]" + ",[Phone],[Mobile],[MaritalStatus] ,[Email] ,[ZipCode],[Address] ,[Street],[City] ,[State] ,[Country],[Photo],[PassportNo]) VALUES (@HRName,@HRCode,@Designation,@Department,@Qulification,@DateOfBirth" + ", @Phone,@Mobile,@MaritalStatus,@Email @ZipCode,@Address,@Street,@City,@State,@Country,,@eimg,@ PassportNo)", con);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HRName", txt_name.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HRCode", txt_code.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Designation", drpdwn_desig.SelectedItem.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department", drpdwn_dept.SelectedItem.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qulification", txt_qual.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfBirth", txt_dob.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(" @Phone", txt_phn.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile", txt_mob.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MaritalStatus", Dropdownmatrialstatus.SelectedItem.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", txt_email.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ZipCode", txt_zip.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", txt_addr.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Street", txt_str.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", txt_cty.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", drpdwn_state.SelectedItem.ToString());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Country", txt_ctry.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(",@eimg", img);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ PassportNo", txt_passportno.Text);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        } catch (Exception) {}

    }
}
```

Comment: I think this line is the problem:  `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(",@eimg", img);`  Your `img` variable is of type `FileUpload`.  It is not an image.  Perhaps you meant to put `imgByte` there?  Also, the extra comma just before `@eimg` in that line might be an issue as well.

Comment: i debug the error as yours guided..again i face the errot in catch block.The method or operation is not implemented.